# Is there a way to disable kernel updates?

Tags: package-management, kernel, updates

I run a more recent kernel (2.6.34) than the ones supplied with the Update Manager. I am tired of updates asking me to reboot every week or so and screwing my grub.cfg (this probably deserves it's own question).

How can I disable those updates painlessly?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the newer kernel from a package or source?

Comment: From a separate .deb package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to System → Administration → Synaptic Package Manager.

Highlight the installed kernel and choose Package → Lock Version on the menu bar.

If for some reason you still get prompted for update you can use

`sudo aptitude hold <the installed kernel package>`

to the same effect.

`dpkg --set-selections` serves the same purpose, too.